# RemoteView with Notification unable to show

Tags: android, notifications, remoteview

I am trying to display RemoteView in android with Notification. I am unable to figure out what is wrong can any one please help me:

Following is my code

```
Bitmap bitmap = MediaManager.getAlbumArt(id, getApplicationContext());
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
                R.layout.remote_layout);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.remote_title, title);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.remote_album, album);

        remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.remote_art,
                R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        // if (bitmap != null)
        // remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.remote_art, bitmap);
        // else
        // remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.remote_art,
        // R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this).setContent(remoteViews).setContentText("SOME TEXT");

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = builder.build();
        // manager.notify(25, notification);
        startService(new Intent(this, MediaServiceContoller.class));
        startForeground(25, notification);
```

Comment: Whats is wrong in this code?

Comment: @KP_ Its isn't showing the Notification